Top alignment of chapter page numbers in TOC
I have a document with some fairly long chapter titles that cannot be shortened. In the table of contents, the page on which the chapter starts is aligned to the last line of the chapter title. I would like the page number to be aligned to the top of the chapter title, but I'm not managing to do so.
MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A Very Long Chapter Title That Wraps Over Two Lines and Needs Top Alignment}
\chapter{Another Chapter Title}

\end{document}


Do you need the long title in theToC? If not, you can use the optional argument \chapter[shorter title for toc]{very long title}

Unfortunately, I do, but thank you for the suggestion!
